# How to programatically detect if my application is running in IIS 7.0 Integrated mode from within an ASP.NET page

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, integrated-pipeline-mode

Generally we should have control of our AppPools and be able to force the Managed Pipeline Mode. In my case I don't have control and would like to implement the code behind code a little differently based on the Managed Pipeline Mode (Integrated vs Classic). I just don't know how to detect this. Is there a simple way to do it from within the code behind page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at [ApplicationPool.ManagedPipelineMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.applicationpool.managedpipelinemode.aspx) and [ServerManager.ApplicationPools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.servermanager.applicationpools.aspx) Properties. So you can examine `ApplicationPool.ManagedPipelineMode` of the current AppPool about like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.applicationpooldefaults.aspx) example do, but to do this for ApplicationPool of your application and not for the default application domain like the example do. The `ServerManager.ApplicationPools` contain all pools including yours one.

Answer (score 11):

I found a way in .NET 4.0 to do this without referencing the `Microsoft.Web.Administration` assembly. The `System.Web.HttpRuntime` class has the `UsingIntegratedPipeline` boolean property.