# Get mode Application Pool programmatically in ASP.NET 4.5

Tags: c#, application-pool, asp.net-4.5, integrated-pipeline-mode

I am running IIS 7.5 Under Windows 2008 R2 (I use Windows 8.1 in development).
I use VS 2012 in Windows 8.1.
I use ASP.NET 4.5. .NET 4.5.1 in my project csproj.

***Programmatically*** *How-to* know if Application Pool mode is **Classic or Integrated** ?

Answer (score 2):

U need to use the `Microsoft.Web.Administration` namespace. You can get this from NuGet or from %WinDir%\System32\InetSrv\Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll

With the `ServerManager` class you can get the applicationpool you need. the property on the applicationpool you're looking for is `ManagedPipelineMode`.

```
var serverManager = new ServerManager();
var appPool = serverManager.ApplicationPools[0]; // get appPool by Index or by appPoolName
var managedPipelineMode = appPool.ManagedPipelineMode;
```

The return value can either be 0 or 1:

0 - Integrated - The managed pipeline runs in Integrated mode.

1 - Classic - The managed pipeline runs in ISAPI mode.

Comment: ***http://stackoverflow.com/a/11275987/206730*** without referencing the `Microsoft.Web.Administration` assembly. The `System.Web.HttpRuntime` class has the `UsingIntegratedPipeline` boolean property.